# Not able to connect to the SQLCMD Utility

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

When I try to connect to the sql server using the sqlcmd  utility, I use the following syntax:

```
 sqlcmd -q "SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Person"
```

I get this following error, can anyone pleae help on this.

```
HResult 0x2, Level 16, State 1
Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : An error has occurred while establi
shing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failu
re may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not
 allow remote connections..
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Native Client : Login timeout expired.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supply the server you wish to connect to:

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -q "SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Person"
```

For instance if you use SQL Server Express `<server>` would be `.\SQLEXPRESS`

For further options of `sqlcmd` use `sqlcmd -?`

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlcmd -S <server> -d <database> -q "query"
```

this syntax worked perfectly for me...

Answer (score 0):

First connect to SQL Server, as:

```
C:\>sqlcmd -U sa -P your_password
```

Then enter queries:

```
SELECT * FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Person.Person;
```

When you want to exit out of sqlcmd, just type:

```
quit
```

and enter.